# The distance calculated by st_distance is weird

Tags: r, r-sf

I have `sf` objects of `polygon` and `points`. The `polygon` is the county shapefile of China and the `point` is the air pollution monitor stations. The overall task is to calculate the county-level air pollution. For each county, the air pollution should be a weighted average of monitor stations that are within 50 km to the county's centroid. The weights are the distances to the centroid.

Below `county` is the `county shapefile` and `obs.o3` is the monitor stations, in which column `m7` is the air pollution value.

```
head(county) # This is the county.
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -35442.05 ymin: 190475.4 xmax: 2037081 ymax: 3487089
epsg (SRID):    3415
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=18 +lat_2=24 +lat_0=21 +lon_0=114 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=WGS72 +towgs84=0,0,1.9,0,0,0.814,-0.38 +units=m +no_defs
      City District Province new_code                       geometry
1 七台河市   勃利县 黑龙江省   230921 MULTIPOLYGON (((1976368 348...
2 七台河市   新兴区 黑龙江省   230902 MULTIPOLYGON (((1958257 342...
3 七台河市   桃山区 黑龙江省   230903 MULTIPOLYGON (((1961344 341...
4 七台河市 茄子河区 黑龙江省   230904 MULTIPOLYGON (((2026143 343...
5   万宁市   万宁市   海南省   469006 MULTIPOLYGON (((135711.6 29...
6   三亚市   三亚市   海南省   460300 MULTIPOLYGON (((15412.51 24...
```

```
head(obs.o3) # This is the monitor stations. Column m7 is the air pollution.
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 116.17 ymin: 39.8673 xmax: 116.473 ymax: 40.2865
epsg (SRID):    3415
proj4string:    +proj=lcc +lat_1=18 +lat_2=24 +lat_0=21 +lon_0=114 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=WGS72 +towgs84=0,0,1.9,0,0,0.814,-0.38 +units=m +no_defs
  station     date     m7                geometry
1   1001A 20150102 36.750 POINT (116.366 39.8673)
2   1002A 20150102 59.750  POINT (116.17 40.2865)
3   1003A 20150102 35.250 POINT (116.434 39.9522)
4   1004A 20150102 36.375 POINT (116.434 39.8745)
5   1005A 20150102 44.125 POINT (116.473 39.9716)
6   1006A 20150102 32.250 POINT (116.361 39.9425)
```

I can calculate the distances between county centroid and monitor points. However, the distances look weird. The code to calcualte distance is

```
county_centroid <- st_centroid(county[,'geometry'])
dis <- st_distance(county_centroid, obs.o3[,'geometry'])
# Please note that I performed some manipulation to add back informations on City, District, etc.
# See the distances below.
```

and the distances look like below. `1001A`, `1002A` etc. are monitor station codes. Finally, I am not sure how to achieve the main task, i.e. calculating county-level air pollution. Please let me know if you need more information.

```
> dis[1:20,1:17]
       City District Province new_code     1001A     1002A     1003A     1004A     1005A     1006A     1007A     1008A     1009A     1010A     1011A     1012A     1013A
1  七台河市   勃利县 黑龙江省   230921 3944036.1 3944035.8 3944036.0 3944036.1 3944035.9 3944036.0 3944036.0 3944035.7 3944035.5 3944035.9 3944036.0 3944036.1 3944036.4
2  七台河市   新兴区 黑龙江省   230902 3935110.4 3935110.1 3935110.3 3935110.4 3935110.3 3935110.3 3935110.3 3935110.0 3935109.8 3935110.2 3935110.3 3935110.4 3935110.7
3  七台河市   桃山区 黑龙江省   230903 3936322.2 3936321.9 3936322.1 3936322.2 3936322.1 3936322.1 3936322.1 3936321.8 3936321.6 3936322.0 3936322.1 3936322.2 3936322.5
4  七台河市 茄子河区 黑龙江省   230904 3973829.5 3973829.2 3973829.4 3973829.4 3973829.3 3973829.4 3973829.4 3973829.1 3973828.9 3973829.3 3973829.3 3973829.5 3973829.8
5    万宁市   万宁市   海南省   469006  287491.0  287490.7  287490.9  287490.9  287490.8  287490.9  287490.9  287490.6  287490.4  287490.7  287490.8  287491.0  287491.4
6    三亚市   三亚市   海南省   460300  215790.5  215790.1  215790.5  215790.5  215790.4  215790.5  215790.4  215790.2  215790.0  215790.2  215790.4  215790.5  215791.3
7    三明市   三元区   福建省   350403 1375145.8 1375145.6 1375145.7 1375145.7 1375145.6 1375145.7 1375145.7 1375145.3 1375145.2 1375145.6 1375145.6 1375145.8 1375145.9
8    三明市   大田县   福建省   350425 1359911.1 1359910.9 1359911.0 1359911.1 1359911.0 1359911.1 1359911.0 1359910.7 1359910.5 1359910.9 1359911.0 1359911.2 1359911.2
9    三明市   宁化县   福建省   350424 1332689.1 1332688.9 1332689.0 1332689.1 1332689.0 1332689.1 1332689.1 1332688.7 1332688.5 1332688.9 1332689.0 1332689.2 1332689.3
10   三明市   将乐县   福建省   350428 1413620.0 1413619.7 1413619.8 1413619.9 1413619.8 1413619.9 1413619.9 1413619.5 1413619.4 1413619.8 1413619.8 1413620.0 1413620.1
11   三明市   尤溪县   福建省   350426 1418484.5 1418484.3 1418484.4 1418484.4 1418484.3 1418484.4 1418484.4 1418484.0 1418483.9 1418484.3 1418484.3 1418484.5 1418484.5
12   三明市   建宁县   福建省   350430 1385601.6 1385601.4 1385601.5 1385601.6 1385601.5 1385601.5 1385601.5 1385601.2 1385601.0 1385601.4 1385601.5 1385601.6 1385601.8
13   三明市   明溪县   福建省   350421 1374944.2 1374944.0 1374944.1 1374944.2 1374944.1 1374944.2 1374944.2 1374943.8 1374943.6 1374944.1 1374944.1 1374944.3 1374944.4
14   三明市   梅列区   福建省   350402 1391516.5 1391516.3 1391516.4 1391516.4 1391516.3 1391516.4 1391516.4 1391516.1 1391515.9 1391516.3 1391516.4 1391516.5 1391516.6
15   三明市   永安市   福建省   350481 1338612.1 1338611.9 1338612.0 1338612.1 1338612.0 1338612.1 1338612.0 1338611.7 1338611.5 1338611.9 1338612.0 1338612.2 1338612.2
16   三明市     沙县   福建省   350427 1415087.8 1415087.6 1415087.7 1415087.7 1415087.6 1415087.7 1415087.7 1415087.3 1415087.2 1415087.6 1415087.6 1415087.8 1415087.9
17   三明市   泰宁县   福建省   350429 1408835.1 1408834.9 1408835.0 1408835.1 1408835.0 1408835.1 1408835.0 1408834.7 1408834.5 1408834.9 1408835.0 1408835.1 1408835.3
18   三明市   清流县   福建省   350423 1328607.7 1328607.5 1328607.6 1328607.7 1328607.6 1328607.7 1328607.7 1328607.3 1328607.2 1328607.6 1328607.6 1328607.8 1328607.9
19 三门峡市   义马市   河南省   411281 2059576.9 2059576.5 2059576.8 2059576.9 2059576.8 2059576.8 2059576.8 2059576.6 2059576.3 2059576.6 2059576.8 2059576.9 2059577.5
20 三门峡市   卢氏县   河南省   411224 1961980.5 1961980.1 1961980.4 1961980.5 1961980.4 1961980.5 1961980.4 1961980.2 1961980.0 1961980.2 1961980.4 1961980.5 1961981.2
```

Comment: Comparing the coordinates geometry of `county` and `county_centroid`, they seem to be on different coordinate-systems. Perhaps this explains your problem? I cannot investigate further, since sample data is not provides using `dput()`..

Comment: I check the crs. They are the same. I also provide a subsample of `county`and the full sample of `point`. Please help me on this :).

Comment: @Wimpel Hi I tried to use `dput()` to include a subsample, however the output for `county` is extremely long even for a single county. The output for `monitor points` are fine.

Comment: crs  can  be set to anything... does not mean  it is the right one...

Comment: @Wimpel Yes, I totally agree with you, and it might be the crs problem. There are so many crs available. I am not quite sure which one to choose. The challenge here is how to achieve the main task, i.e. calculating the county-level air pollution in an efficient way. This has been bothering me for several days......